# Google analytics ecommerce with delayed payments

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

With a paypal like system it's easy to track the transaction with the auto-return setting and `?utm_nooverride=1` parameter, since after the payment the user is redirected back to the site.

But what if we have a system with delayed payments? 
User adds to cart, checkout, but he just pays for the transaction tomorrow.

Is it possible to track a transaction like this? 
I'm able to store some vars and pass them to the callback function to later use.

Answer (score 0):

just as a sidenote here, in your case, there is no need to use 'utm_nooverride=1', since usually it wont take more than 30 minutes to checkout on the paying service site, the visit will be maintained when the visitor returns to your site.

About your question, unfortunately there is no way to achieve this kind of transaction, because the transaction is a visit-related tracking, and when the user comes back tomorrow to pay, it will be a new visit.

Also, as probably the user doesn´t really have to go back to your site to finish his purchase, I don´t really see the possibility.

Augusto Roselli
Web Analytics - [dp6](http://www.dp6.com.br)